# How to create a blank action in Asp.net MVC for redirect

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, webforms, payment-gateway

I am not sure if this is possible or not, but it is something I need to do at work.

At present we are using e24PaymentPipe system from ACI to handle payment in our MVC website. The payment response page is a .aspx page with only redirect page.
When I used a MVC action I would get error from payment gateway. **For time being I am using .aspx** but it is not secure, plus I have to handle session and other values manually between MVC and .aspx page.

**.aspx page**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>

<script runat="server">
    protected void Page_Load(Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            String result = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request["result"];

            String paymentID = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request["paymentid"];

            String respons = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request["responsecode"];

            String err = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request["Error"];

            String errmsg = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request["ErrorText"];

            String tid = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request["Trackid"];

            String udf2 = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request["udf2"];

            String _sessionVal = "";

            if (Session != null && (Session["XXX"] == null || Session["XXX"] != "Valid"))
                Session["XXX"] = "Valid";
            else if (Session != null)
                _sessionVal = Session["XXX"].ToString();

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(result) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(respons))
            {
                String query = String.Format("/checkout/BenefitPaymentResult?result={0}&paymentid={1}&responsecode={2}&error={3}&errortext={4}&trackid={5}", result, paymentID, respons, err, errmsg, tid);
                if (udf2 == "test")
                {
                    Response.Redirect("http://localhost:15536" + query);
                }
                Response.Redirect(query);
            }
            else
            {
                Response.Redirect("/cart");
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

**Controller Action:**

```
public ActionResult BenefitPaymentResult()
        {
            var cart = _workContext.CurrentCustomer.ShoppingCartItems.Where(sci => sci.ShoppingCartType == ShoppingCartType.ShoppingCart)
              .LimitPerStore(_storeContext.CurrentStore.Id)
              .ToList();
            try
            {
                // transaction response code
                String _result = (Request.QueryString["result"] != null && Request.QueryString["result"].Length > 0) ? Request.QueryString["result"] : "null";
                String _paymentId = (Request.QueryString["paymentid"] != null && Request.QueryString["paymentid"].Length > 0) ? Request.QueryString["paymentid"] : "null";
                String _response = (Request.QueryString["responsecode"] != null && Request.QueryString["responsecode"].Length > 0) ? Request.QueryString["responsecode"] : "null";
                String _err = (Request.QueryString["Error"] != null && Request.QueryString["Error"].Length > 0) ? Request.QueryString["Error"] : "null";
                String _errMessage = (Request.QueryString["ErrorText"] != null && Request.QueryString["ErrorText"].Length > 0) ? Request.QueryString["ErrorText"] : "null";
                String _trackID = (Request.QueryString["Trackid"] != null && Request.QueryString["Trackid"].Length > 0) ? Request.QueryString["Trackid"] : "null";
                // define message string for errors
                String _message = getResponseDescription(_response);
                var order = _orderService.GetOrderById(Convert.ToInt32(_trackID));
                if (_result.Equals("CAPTURED"))
                {
                    cart.ToList().ForEach(sci => _shoppingCartService.DeleteShoppingCartItem(sci, false));
                    return RedirectToRoute("CheckoutCompleted", new { orderId = order.Id });
                }
                else
                {
                    _orderService.UpdateOrder(order);
                    order.CaptureTransactionResult = _message;
                    _orderProcessingService.CancelOrder(order, true);
                    return Redirect(Url.Action("Confirm", "Checkout"));
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {               
                return Redirect(Url.Action("Confirm", "Checkout"));
            }
        }
```

When **using "Action"** to handle response, bank told me following:

**The response page contain html code and as we informed you it must contain only the redirect page. Please do your testing under test environment then shift it to production**

**Error:**

09:38:40,872 FATAL event.com.aciworldwide.commerce.gateway.payment.MerchantNotificationService [TP-Processor5]  - Hack characer/length check failed on redirect URL:

```
         <!DOCTYPE html>
         <html lang="en">
         <head>
             <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
             <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9">
```

How do I create a blank action to mimic the .aspx page code above? Cant find anything related to this. There is no ACI demo code for MVC either!

Comment: @haim770 if you read carefully that is exactly what I said mate! At present I am using .aspx page to handle redirect from gateway in my MVC project. I am not able to use MVC action. If I use the same code in action, I get the error in payment. Which I have shared above. Thanks!

Comment: @haim770 you should read the whole post, I have highlighted some text and added some more for clarification.

Comment: Where is your code for (`controller`) `Action` that handles the test request from your payment provider? Based on above, it _seems_ you're trying to handle things at some "page" level (in some `vb`/`cshtml` `view`) like your `aspx` code instead of `controller` level.

Comment: @EdSF I mentioned that when I use same code in aciton I get error. Anyway I have added the action code, I hope this would help you help me :) Thanks!

Comment: Hmm..I don't see anything "wrong", but then again, I'm not familiar with the API you mention. Reading their response, you probably need to ask for clarification - when they mention "no `html`" and then "only `page`" in the same sentence. Do they mean just `http` `headers`? Just the redirect `url`? Seems better for you to go directly to provider support for specifics...hth.